# Extract xml data when child node names are unknown

Tags: php, mysql, xml, child-nodes

I have a quiz system from iSpring Solutions that sends xml results data to my php script. I want to extract information to update a mysql database.

Each quiz has different questions so the xml file is not always the same length/structure, however I need to get specific data.

Here is an extract from the xml file

```
<questions>

    <matchingQuestion id="{3F033905-566A-4B67-B7E4-324E4367FD16}" status="correct" maxPoints="2" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="2" usedAttempts="1">
      <direction>Match the items on the left with the items on the right</direction>
    </matchingQuestion>

    <fillInTheBlankQuestionEx id="{6FCC5DAC-168F-4F44-87DF-9B1D162268D1}" status="partially" maxPoints="8" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="4" usedAttempts="1">
      <direction>Which indefinite article should be written in front of the following words - 'a' or 'an'?</direction>
    </fillInTheBlankQuestionEx>

  </questions>
```

I need to 
(a) get the name/id of each child node
(b) get the id, status, maxPoints values
(c) then get the 'direction' value

The node name 'matchingQuestion' or 'fillInTheBlankQuestionEx' always change order depending on the quiz.

I can't figure out how to get these values as the question types vary for each quiz!

Many thanks in advance

John

The full xml file is:

```
    <quizReport xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults quizReport.xsd" version="1" xmlns="http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring/quizbuilder/quizresults" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <quizSettings quizType="graded" maxScore="10" maxNormalizedScore="100" timeLimit="180">
    <passingPercent>0.8</passingPercent>
  </quizSettings>
  <summary score="2" percent="0.2" time="6">
    <variables>
      <variable name="VARIABLE_2" title="DFE number (7 digit)" value="2112377"/>
      <variable name="USER_NAME" title="Your name" value="John"/>
      <variable name="VARIABLE_1" title="Your class" value="6M"/>
    </variables>
  </summary>
  <questions>
    <matchingQuestion id="{3F033905-566A-4B67-B7E4-324E4367FD16}" status="correct" maxPoints="2" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="2" usedAttempts="1">
      <direction>Match the items on the left with the items on the right</direction>
      <premises>
        <premise>an</premise>
        <premise>a</premise>
      </premises>
      <responses>
        <response>elephant</response>
        <response>house</response>
      </responses>
      <matches>
        <match premiseIndex="0" responseIndex="0"/>
        <match premiseIndex="1" responseIndex="1"/>
      </matches>
      <userAnswer>
        <match premiseIndex="0" responseIndex="0"/>
        <match premiseIndex="1" responseIndex="1"/>
      </userAnswer>
    </matchingQuestion>
    <fillInTheBlankQuestionEx id="{6FCC5DAC-168F-4F44-87DF-9B1D162268D1}" status="incorrect" maxPoints="8" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="0" usedAttempts="1">
      <direction>Which indefinite article should be written in front of the following words - 'a' or 'an'?</direction>
      <details>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>a</answer>
          <answer>a</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ television
]]></text>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>a</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ boy
]]></text>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>an</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ umbrella
]]></text>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>a</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ house
]]></text>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>an</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ hour
]]></text>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>an</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ igloo
]]></text>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>a</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ minute
]]></text>
        <blank userAnswer="" correct="false">
          <answer>an</answer>
        </blank>
        <text><![CDATA[ elephant]]></text>
      </details>
    </fillInTheBlankQuestionEx>
  </questions>
</quizReport>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code that you came up with as a base to start from.

Answer (score 0):

To begin your codding, i  show an example. Suppose, $text contains xml

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($text);
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($xml->questions->children() as $q) {
//      print_r($q); echo '<br/>';
        print_r((string)$q->getName());echo '<br/>';
        print_r((string)$q->attributes()->id);echo '<br/>';
        print_r((string)$q->direction);echo '<br/>';
}
```

result:

```
matchingQuestion
{3F033905-566A-4B67-B7E4-324E4367FD16}
Match the items on the left with the items on the right
fillInTheBlankQuestionEx
{6FCC5DAC-168F-4F44-87DF-9B1D162268D1}
Which indefinite article should be written in front of the following words - 'a' or 'an'?
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply, I used the code below, from Splash58 to re-write the php that is updating a mysql database:

```
    foreach ($xml->questions->children() as $q) {
$QuestionType=(string)$q->getName();
$QuestionUUID=(string)$q->attributes()->id;
$QuestionAsked=(string)$q->direction;

$query="INSERT INTO questions (UUID, Qtype, Question) VALUES ('".$QuestionUUID."', '".$QuestionType."', '".$QuestionAsked."')";
$mysqli->query($query);

}
```

However, only the first question is being added to the DB.

Comment: I've tryed  by myself  :)- in second case $QuestionAsked contains quotes,  you  should use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Hurrah! Worked like a dream! Thank you so very much!